# Estilos CSS no aparecen si los elementos están dentro de una función

Tags: javascript, css

no consigo que CSS aplique los estilos de los elementos "phoras, pminutos, psegundos, pdia, pmes, pyear" cuando estas variables se ejecutan dentro de la función "sendMessage"

Os resumo el problema con el ejemplo de la variable "phoras":

```
fecha = new Date(),
horas = fecha.getHours(),

[...]

phoras = document.getElementById ("horas").innerHTML=horas;
```

Y esta sería la función (la pego con todas las variables de tiempo introducidas):

```
function sendMessage() {

  var message = document.getElementById("typing-box").value;
  var reloj = (" "+ phoras + ":" + pminutos + ":" + psegundos + " | " + pdia + " de " + pmes + " del " + pyear);
  var html = nombreUsuario + reloj +
        '<div class="message-box my-message-box">' +
        '<div class="message my-message"> ' + message + ' </div>' +
        '<div class="separator"></div>';

  document.getElementById("message-area").innerHTML += html;
  document.getElementById("typing-box").value = "";
}
```

Luego, en HTML tengo el siguiente Div, que es el que está trayendo el .innerHTML para ser rellenado, como veis tiene una clase "tiempo":

```
<div id = "horas" class ="tiempo"></div>
```

Por último en CSS tengo:

```
.tiempo {
    display:inline-block;
    color:rgb(145, 145, 145);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Os paso el enlace de todo el proyecto para que podáis verlo mejor:
https://github.com/Ananekos/APP-Mensajer-a-GeeksHub

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puede ser porque el div del html tiene un id horas y desde el js esta llamando a otro id `document.getElementById("message-area").innerHTML += html;` se ve como haces el innerHTML a message-area

Answer (score 0):

Primero, las variables no se ejecutan son un valor. phoras, pminutos,...., son un valor. Si lo que quieres es añadir los elementos html tienes que eliminar el .innerHtml. Ej. phoras = document.getElementbyId("horas"); pero si solo quieres el valor, tendrás que ponerle la clase tiempo al elemento con id "message-area".

Segundo, por lo que me parece ver, en la función sendMessage las variables esas son nulas, ya que no existen en ese ámbito.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que el valor de `phoras` es lo que hay dentro de la etiqueta `html`, es decir, el valor. Si haces un `console.log` de phoras tras definirlo puedes verlo. Para que te aplique la clase puedes añadir la etiqueta `html` en `reloj`.

```js
let mesesDelAño = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre",];

(function relojPrincipal() {

  var actualizarHora =function(){
      fecha = new Date(),
      horas = fecha.getHours(),
      minutos = fecha.getMinutes(),
      segundos = fecha.getSeconds(),
      dia = fecha.getDate(),
      mes = fecha.getMonth(),
      year = fecha.getFullYear(),

  
      phoras = document.getElementById ("horas").innerHTML=horas,
      pminutos = document.getElementById ("minutos").innerHTML=minutos,
      psegundos = document.getElementById ("segundos").innerHTML=segundos,
      pdia = document.getElementById ("dia").innerHTML=dia,
      pmes = document.getElementById ("mes").innerHTML=mesesDelAño[mes],
      pyear = document.getElementById ("year").innerHTML=year,
    
      
      pdia.innerHTML = dia,

      pmes.innerHTML = mesesDelAño [mes],

      pyear.innerHTML = year;

      if (phoras < 10) {phoras = "0" + phoras};
      if (pminutos < 10) {pminutos = "0" + pminutos};
      if (psegundos < 10) {psegundos = "0" + psegundos};

      phoras.innerHTML = horas;
      pminutos.innerHTML = minutos;
      psegundos.innerHTML = segundos;
      //console.log(phoras);

  };

  actualizarHora();
  var intervalo = setInterval(actualizarHora,1000);

}())


var nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("nom_usuario").innerHTML;
function sendMessage() {

  var message = document.getElementById("typing-box").value;
  var reloj = (" <p class='tiempo'>"+ phoras + ":" + pminutos + ":" + psegundos + " | " + pdia + " de " + pmes + " del " + pyear + "</p>");
  var html = nombreUsuario + reloj +
        '<div class="message-box my-message-box">' +
        '<div class="message my-message"> ' + message + ' </div>' +
        '<div class="separator"></div>';

  document.getElementById("message-area").innerHTML += html;
  document.getElementById("typing-box").value = "";
}
```

```css
.tiempo {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #21c921;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont_der">
            <div class="cont_top">
                <hr class="linea_gris">
                <div class="cont_participantes"> <d1>Nombre del canal</d1> 
                    <div class="barra_busqueda">
                        <button class="boton_busqueda"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        <input type="text" class="input_busqueda">
                    </div>
                    <br><d4>Participantes</d4>
                <hr class="linea_gris_2">
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="message-area" id="message-area">

            
                
                <div id="nom_interlocutor"><img src="IMG/iconito_2.png" class="iconito_usuario">
                    <d2>Olivia Montes</d2> <d3>12:15:23</d3><d5>  |  5 de Febrero del 2022</d5></div>
                <div class="message-box others-message-box">
                    <div class="message others-message"> Hola, ¿qué tal?. Bienvenid@ al canal.</div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                    
                <div id="nom_usuario" hidden><img src="IMG/iconito_1.png" class="iconito_usuario"><d2>Alumno@ BTC</d2></div>
                <div id = "fecha_hora" class = "fecha_hora" hidden>
                    <d5 id = "horas" class ="tiempo"></d5>
                    <p class ="tiempo">:</p>
                    <p id = "minutos" class ="tiempo"></p>
                    <p class ="tiempo">:</p>
                    <p id = "segundos" class ="tiempo"></p>
                    <p class ="tiempo"> | </p>
                    <p id = "dia" class ="tiempo"></p>
                    <p class ="tiempo"> de </p>
                    <p id = "mes" class ="tiempo"></p>
                    <p class ="tiempo"> del </p>
                    <p id = "year" class ="tiempo"></p>
                </div>
                   
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="message-box others-message-box">
                    <div class="message others-message"> Hi, How are you? </div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="message-box my-message-box">
                    
                    <div class="message my-message"> I am good, how are you doing? </div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="cont_bottom">
                    <div class="typing-area">
                        <button class="send-button" onclick="sendMessage()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">Send</i></button>
                        <textarea class="typing-box" id="typing-box"></textarea>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                
            
            </div>     
        </div>
```

Comment: Si!!! Era eso! Muchas gracias!!! :)

Comment: @AnaFernández Si esta respuesta te ha sido útil deberías aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa. Pulsa en [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas. También te recomiendo leerte [tour] para que aprendas bien el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.